# getStaticProps showing wrong/previous data in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Rectjs,I am using nextjs, I created "[slug.js]" for dynamic routes,But its showing previous data instead of current data(fetching from database via axios),I checked in console.log,and in console showing old data not current,where i am wrong ?Here is my current code

```
const Post = function ({post}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // showing old record/title instead of current
    console.log(`Found Post title : ${post.title}`);
  }, []);
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/getblogbyuserid/${params.slug}`
  );
  const post = data;

  console.log('dat is' + post);

  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    'http://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/blogscopy'
  );
  const posts = data.slice(0, 10);
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({ params: { slug: post.id.toString() } }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};
```

Comment: is your `params.id` correct

Comment: @sachila Ranawaka yes

Comment: did you get the correct data when u console log inside the getStaticProps?

Comment: The approach you need is next's ISR. Try adding ` revalidate: 1` to getStaticPaths return value. Check the documentation about revalidate [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#revalidate)